# How do you stop this random number warning?

Tags: random, warnings

I get warning (c++ environment)

```
 /Usr/main.cpp:35: warning: overflow in expression; result is -2147483648 with type 'int' [-Winteger-overflow]
r= rand()/static_cast<REAL>(RAND_MAX+1);
                                    ^
```

My code is

```
typedef double REAL;
REAL X=2.5;

REAL r= rand()/static_cast<REAL>(RAND_MAX+1);
xs=((REAL)(0 + static_cast<int>( r * (100*X - 0) )))/100;
```

I am trying to generate a random number between 0 and 2.5 within 2 decimal accuracy.

Is this warning serious? and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is this C++? Can you please provide some context?

Comment: The largest allowed `int` in C++ is 2,147,483,64**7**. RAND_MAX+1 is 2,147,483,64**8**

Comment: I am trying to get a random number (double) between 0 and X and for this I do " r= ((REAL)rand())/static_cast<REAL>(RAND_MAX+1);
    xs=((REAL)(0 + static_cast<int>( r * (100*X - 0) )))/100;

Comment: @TylerRoper updated

Comment: Truthfully I'm not a C++ programmer. However if `RAND_MAX+1` is return a value *one greater than what's allowed for an `int` in C++*, why not just change it to `RAND_MAX`?